# How to pass a React Hook to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass the setter of a React Hook to a Child Component. So that a button in the child component updates the state via setter which is saved in the Parent Component. I tried following setup but I get an error message :

> TypeError: setshowOptionPC is not a function
>   onClick

Is my approach even possible? And if not how could I possibly do that structure using a React Hook.

Below a simplified version of my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function ChildComponent({ setshowChildOptionBC, setshowChildOptionPC }) (
  <div>
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setshowChildOptionPC(false);
        setshowChildOptionBC(true);
      }}
    >
      BC
    </button>
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setshowChildOptionPC(true);
        setshowChildOptionBC(false);
      }}
    >
      PC
    </button>
  </div>
);


function ParentComponent() {
  const [showOptionBC, setshowOptionBC] = useState(true);
  const [showOptionPC, setshowOptionPC] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent
        setshowChildOptionBC={setshowOptionBC}
        setshowChildOptionPC={setshowOptionPC}
      />
      {showOptionBC && <div>BC</div>}
      {showOptionPC && <div>PC</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Comment: `function ChildComponent({ setshowOptionBC, setshowOptionPC })` you’re missing the braces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just forgot to destructure props in your child component.
This might help.

```
function ChildComponent({setshowOptionBC, setshowOptionPC}) {..
```