# how to send the data from one component to another component when i press a button. React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I have a table where i render a data from the pokemon api, well in the table i have a button and when you press the button you get the data from the arrow, so i want to send that data from my component table to another component card and in that card render only the data which you select from the table. But i don't know how to send the data to my component Card whitout render my card five times in my table. Now i get the data when i press the button, i just need to send him.

**Rows on the table component**

```
export const Lista = (props) => {
    
    const [, setPokeSelec] = useState({
    })
    
    const selectArrow = ( poke ) => {

        setPokeSelec( poke );
        console.log(poke);
    }
    
    return (

        <>
            <TableRow key={ props.info.id }>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    { props.info.id }
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{ props.info.name }</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{ props.info.abilities[0].ability.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">
                    <img src={ props.info.sprites.front_default } alt={ props.info.name } style={{ height: 60 }} />
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">
                    <Button 
                        variant="contained" 
                        color="primary" 
                        size="small" 
                        onClick={ () => selectArrow( props.info ) }
                    >
                        Seleccionar
                    </Button>
                    </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Card component**

```
export const Informacion = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={ classes.margen } >
            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                <Card className={classes.root}>
                    <CardMedia
                        className={classes.cover}
                        image={pika}
                        title="Live from space album cover"
                    />
                    <div className={classes.details}>
                        <CardContent className={classes.content}>

                        <Typography component="h5" variant="h5">
                            Pikachu
                        </Typography>

                        <Divider/>

                        <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="textPrimary">
                            Tipo:
                        </Typography>

                        </CardContent>
                    </div>
                </Card>
            </Box>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**PokemonApi Component**
Here i call the API, render the table and send to my component table the data

export const PokemonApi = () => {

```
const classes = useStyles();
const [poke, setPoke] = useState([]);


const data = () => {        
    
    axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100`).then(( response ) => {

        for(let i = 0; i < response.data.results.length; i++  ) {
            axios.get(response.data.results[i].url)
            .then( result => {
                setPoke(prevArray => [...prevArray, result.data])
                // console.log(result.data);
            })
        }
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.log(err);
    })

}

useEffect(() => {

    data()

}, []);

return (

    <>


        <TableContainer className={ classes.margin } component={Paper}>
            <Table className={ classes.table } size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Name&nbsp;</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Type&nbsp;</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Img&nbsp;</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Actions&nbsp;</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    { poke.map((infos, name) => <Lista key={name} info={infos}/>) }
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    </>
)
```

}

**This is the page where i render the card and the PokemonApi**

```
export const Pokes = () => {

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="md">
            <PokemonApi />
            <Informacion />
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: where do you render this `card` component? Can you please create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can check it and test out

Comment: @Sowam         i render the card component on a page called pokes, in that page i render two components: PokemonApi, in that component i make the call to the api, render the table and send the  data to my component table (the rows). The second component is the card component.

I edited the post with the PokemonApi component and the page who contains the components

Answer (score 0):

Here are the common ways to pass data from a component A to a component B :

1. Having the component B as a child of the component A (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860513/how-to-pass-a-react-hook-to-a-child-component))
2. Having the component A as a child of the component B, with a callback prop that gets fired in the component A (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55727244/11644918))
3. Using the [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Hope that this answer helped you